# How to fix shortest path on google map to reach a destination from current location?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I never did work on goggle map, i want to fix the shortest path on Google Map.
I want to specify the destination location on the goggle map and current location should be taken automatically where i am seating, then I want to specify shortest path in some color full way to reach the destination.
How should I implement this web based project, could somebody please direction me for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google api key for map for this and you can set yours geolocations that is your latitude and longitude and call the API function to find the shortest path between the source and destination place
You can aslo have a look at : 
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/this-is-how-you-use-the-google-maps-api/
also you can see a demo app at :
http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html
thanks